# How can I sign in a Wordpress (mu) user from outside of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working for a company that is using Wordpress MU to supplement other functions on a member site. We have a user signup process that creates the appropriate Wordpress MU users and blogs on signup, but I'm having real trouble figuring out how to log someone in to a WP blog from outside of Wordpress itself. The documentation these methods seem to be non-existent or just too obtuse for me.

In the abstract I know how to do it: Take user info, set the same cookie that Wordpress would set itself. Done. It is, however, not this simple.

Has anyone done this successfully before?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to log people into Wordpress, however I'm was running inside Wordpress. (I was inside a theme)

Basically, the tough part is getting all the hashes correct, because Wordpress uses a set of defined security hashes in the config file to create the cookie. Ideally you should be able to copy and paste the functions that Wordpress uses.

Yes Wordpress documentation for security sucks, but that is what you get in a Open Source application, not stellar documentation.

What you are looking for is the wp_set_auth_cookie function in the /wp-includes/pluggable.php file. You should look into what the do_action()s actually do, but you should be able to simply replace all the constants with the correct values, and you'll have a function that can port anywhere on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, it's not so tough task, once you are using correct instruments ;)
Try [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support)