# How to do WordPress user signup and login outside of WordPress

Tags: android, wordpress, authentication

This is a follow up to [Is there an API for bbPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319487/is-there-an-api-for-bbpress). I have confirmed that both bbPress and buddyPress uses WordPress user registration and login processes. They all the same. No difference.

What I want is to register and sign in the users of my WordPress site from my Android app.

I have come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1153390/6181476) that talks about [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) but I am still lost.
Please do you have any idea how this can be done? Whether with this XML-RPC or any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a php script for handling user [login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate)/[logout](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout). Include wp-load.php to this php script this way you can use wordpress functions in external php file.
Then you can send login data to GET or POST method to this script.

Comment: Thanks bro. Please where do I keep this php script? And how do I send login data to it. A verbose explanation will be very appreciated.